# Base condition in recursive methods

Tags: java

I am wondering about the base condition in the recursive methods. in my lectures I see that my teacher some times write the base condition in various ways. See this please  :

Here the base condition in the public method

```
public E find(E x) {
  if (x == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return find(root,x);
}

private E find(BinaryNode<E> n, E x) {
    if (n.element.equals(x)) {
        return n.element;
    }
    else if (x.compareTo(n.element) < 0) {
        return find(n.left, x);
    }
    else {
        return find(n.right, x);
    }
}
```

is it OK if I write the base condition in the private method like this :

```
public E find(E x) {
    return find(root,x);
}

private E find(BinaryNode<E> n, E x) {
    if (n == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (n.element.equals(x)) {
        return n.element;
    }
    else if (x.compareTo(n.element) < 0) {
        return find(n.left, x);
    }
    else {
        return find(n.right, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put relevant code here, in your question; don't rely on external links, which may die.

Comment: What do you think happens in the first case if `n.left` (or `n.right`) is `null`?

Comment: Did you mean `if (x == null)` instead of `if (n == null)` ?

Comment: I think it will not work , i will get a problem

Comment: @AndyTurner The strange thing is that this will always happen when the element isn't in the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I would pick the following version:

```
public E find(E x) {
    return find(root,x);
}

private E find(BinaryNode<E> n, E x) {
    if (n == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (n.element.equals(x)) {
        return n.element;
    }
    else if (x.compareTo(n.element) < 0) {
        return find(n.left, x);
    }
    else {
        return find(n.right, x);
    }
}
```

Why? Because it's correct. The other one isn't and would lead to the `NullPointerException` in case there is no such element in the tree.

The second question which appears in the OP post and the comment is whether to put the base condition in a `public` or a `private` method. The only possible correct answer is that each recursive method must have a base condition on which the recurrence will end.

`public` methods can be called *by everyone* so they should validate the input. They cannot assume that the parameters are valid. `private` methods can assume that parameters are ok and can focus on their logic.

The condition I would put in your public method would be:

```
public E find(E x) {
    if (<x isn't valid - for example null and nulls are not allowed for values>) {
        //do something here - exception or null
    }
    return find(root,x);
}
```

It would stand for making sure that the input for the private find...` would be correct. That's what you have to do.

Comment: thank you when it is ok to write the base condition in the public method?

Comment: @Joe I'll explain in the answer in the minute.

Comment: Well, conceptually the first version is better. It indicates straight by looking at it that the recursive call is used and keep the code clean. Also it saves the extra call to `find(..)` method which is a performance gain.

Comment: @MaxZoom it's simply wrong, though. Throwing a `NullPointerException` is a real downer for performance.

Comment: @MaxZoom the first version leads to NPE

Comment: @AndyTurner but where is the check if `x` is not null? `x` is external parameter that the class does not control so it needs to be checked, while `root` is something that should be keep valid for the class to work.

Comment: The first version *typically* leads to NPE. It might not, for example, if the constructor of class E puts all created objects in the tree, thus guaranteeing that find() will always find them. This is a very unlikely scenario though.

Comment: @MaxZoom `x` becomes `n` in the `private` method.